SINAD and ENOB calculation
I have an ADC which has 14 bit, 100 MHz sampling frequency. I collected data 6.103 kHz sinus wave. I try to calculate SINAD. However, I can't find same result as in MATLAB. Let me explain more.
I create reference sinus for comparing data that collecting from ADC.
To bring phases into in-phase, I compare ref_sin and collect_data signal. I take FFT, I find phase value. I regenerate ref_sin using this phase value. These two signal are in phase.
ref_sin = sin(2*pi*f*t + phase);

I use for finding rms noise.
I used this error difference for finding enob. I use this formula.
I find 14.23 LSB rms noise. I find 8.3767 bits using these codes.
This ENOB used by this formula for finding SINAD. SINAD is 52.1877 dB.
$$
SINAD = 6.02 * N + 1.76
$$
I apply the gain coefficient and offset value to collecting data. This value for fixing linearity error.
I find 9.8489 effective bits. SINAD is 61.05 dB.
I used the sinad MATLAB function. If I use this function for two different data sets, both of them for fixing data or just collecting data is the same value. The value is 64.586 dB.
Why is the SINAD value is the same? My calculation is not correct or we have another reason. How is the correct calculation for ENOB and SINAD value?

how are you calculating the reference ref_sin? that seems to be a pretty non-trivial step with very important effects on all estimations based on it. Also, an ideal 14 bit ADC would have something like -86 dB quantization noise on a full-scale sine wave. How do you generate a sine of that quality? It's technically very feasible, but it's not just "I built an RC oscillator" or "I programmed my DDS".

@MarcusMüller I edited my questions. I use signal generator has very high resolution and low noise/distortion.

"very high resolution": 14 bits is kind of "very high" already, so you really need to be sure of your specs here. Also, note that you need to make sure your ADC sample clock is coherent to your signal generator's clock. most importantly, however, I don't understand how you align the phase of your ref_sin and the analog wave being sampled.

@MarcusMüller The signal generator has 24 bit DAC, enob 21 bits. Just I compare ref_sin and collecting data signal. I take FFT, I find phase value. I regenerate ref_sin using this phase value. These two signal are in phase. Simple and quick.

you need to determine the phase to a very fine degree. How do you do that? The FFT seems to be a bad tool for that, because your frequency is not in any way related to your sampling rate, so you cannot build a leakage-free estimator out of an FFT for that. You can achieve something with interpolation there, but you don't tell us what you actually do, you just say you're doing it "correctly", then ask us about the result which you seem to think is incorrect. See the conflict?

thanks for the edit by the way. What about you actually fix the code above (now you have two conflicting definitions of what ref_sin is), and add the actual code of how you determine the phase?

@MarcusMüller Okey, thanks for your comments. I saw the conflict, sorry about that. I shared code. Another different question. Do you think my calculation or approaching is reasonably adequate without little difference SINAD value?

Really hard to tell – "reasonableness" depends on whether your calculation's assumptions fit the underlying reality, and I can't assess that without a feeling for clock coherence/jitter between generator and ADC, the quality of phase and amplitude recovery (which will quite possibly dominate measurement error!) and noise of the electronics.

phase = phdiffmeasure(ref_sin,collect_data) I'm not sure I understand the method used there if you don't specify it (the function takes 4 arguments, but you only specify two). Please post the full cleaned up code, instead of conflicting fragments

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You will be very sensitive to gain and time offsets as well as any errors in sampling frequency trying to validate ENOB and SINAD using this approach. Unless you generated the reference signal and the quantized result from the same source, there will be a lot of work and room for error to align properly for purposes of measuring such small error signals.
What I do to measure ENOB and SNR from measured data is to work from a power spectral density for estimating the noise contribution. For that we can ignore the tone and use the rest of the spectrum to get a best estimate as to the noise power density (including harmonics or ignoring them as well depending on if SINAD or SNR avoiding harmonics is used).
For this purpose, see this other post DSP.SE #87731 that clarifies how to accurately measure the tone (which should be a "full scale" sine wave) using a properly scaled FFT spectrum, but measure the power spectral density of the noise using the Welch method and why.
Further hints on measuring the tone very accurately: Be sure to use a window and be sure to zero pad the result - this avoids all "scalloping loss" and results in a highly accurate measurement regardless of frequency.

Thank you for your very detailed explanation. I try to welch method. Obviously, I analyzed "sinad" function in MATLAB. This function use kaiser windowing, power spectral density and effective resolution bandwith. You are definitely right. I am confused this point. I apply gain coefficient and offset but sinad function said the same result. How is it possible? Because I calculated the different result for SINAD. Okey, you think, Is my calculations or approaching is correct without welch's method?

I think gain and offset values ​​have no meaning for SNR. But these two values ​​should definitely affect SINAD. Because linearity should completely affect distortion.

Is it normal for MATLAB to give the same SINAD value for both the signal multiplied and summed by certain coefficients and the collected data? Is it because it performs an optimization in the background that gives the same result? As I said, when I correct the data, while the enob I calculated changes, that is, the SINAD changes, how does MATLAB's sinad value not change? I think he should have given different sinad values. What do you think?

@bb0667 why do you think that scaling would affect the SINAD estimate? This is what I'm confused here about! If you can articulate that, it would help us discuss, or even explain things :)

You are subtracting a reference signal from the qauntized signal- if they are not perfectly aligned in time (and if not scaled to be exactly the same other than the quantization) the resulting error will be significant. We’re discouraged from having an extended discussion in the chat so I don’t think I am going to be able to provide you the clarity that you need beyond convince yourself (with simulation if needed) that you can accurately measure the rms of a tone (as “signal”) and the noise density  (multiply the rms density in v_rms/root Hz by the square root of fs to get “noise”. SNR=20log()

@MarcusMüller I edited the question. I hope I can tell in my mind. Thank you.

Also typically the ONLY difference between SNR and SINAD is that harmonics are excluded for SNR (but different manuf define that differently- read their data sheets carefully). Also you need to be very careful that the noise floor of your measurement equipment is significantly (15 dB is good) below the noise floor from the noise your ADC is creating. The “full scale” sine wave is typically 1-2 dB below actually clipping level to maximize the dynamic range between the power of the sine wave and the power from the quantization noise and all other contributions from your ADC and sampling clock.

@DanBoschen , thank you. I definetely agree your last comment. I check the noise floor for signal generator. But for previous comment, I don't understand how to say last part. Any chance of adding a snippet or image of this to your answer? Or a link will be enough for me.

Sure- which comment are you referring to?

"I don’t think I am going to be able to provide you the clarity that you need beyond convince yourself (with simulation if needed) that you can accurately measure the rms of a tone (as “signal”) and the noise density (multiply the rms density in v_rms/root Hz by the square root of fs to get “noise”. SNR=20log()" this one.

This is actually going to be a topic I explain in detail at this years DSP Online Conference next month: https://www.dsponlineconference.com/

@bb0667 here are the details of that: https://www.dsponlineconference.com/workshop/Expert_Insights_into_Waveform_Analysis_Techniques
